# TSM TDP for Exchange backup - ANS0326E

Tags: backup, exchange, tsm

Heres the stack

Server - AIX - 5.3.0
BAclient - NT 32 bit 5.5.2.0
TDP for Exchange - 5.2.1

Backups are failing with ANS0326E (RC41) This node has exceeded its maximum number of moint points

MAXNUMMP on the node is 1, which is the same as the other 2 exchange servers being backed up using this product. Only difference is that baclient version - on the working setup the baclient is at 5.4.0.2. Clues anyone?